# Create a hidden image when I check if I have an entry in my database

Tags: php, html, image, hidden

my problem is that I want to check in my database that if i have at least one entry in the specific table I want to disable an image.

I think that I can have something like that...

```
<?php
    if($query = mysql_query("SELECT name,email,city,phone FROM personal_information WHERE username='$username'"))
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)=0)
        {
            <a href="cv/addcv.php"><img src="images/addcv.png" style="display: none;"> </a>
        }
        else
        {
             <a href="cv/addcv.php"><img src="images/addcv.png" style="width:120px;height:120px"> </a>
        }
    }
?>
```

But it does not work...
Can you suggest me any solution

Comment: `if(mysql_num_rows($query)=0)` use either `>` or `!=`. the `echo` is no where to be found

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php A comparison operator is this for example `==`

Comment: **Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo).** **[Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

Comment: please dont use mysql_ anymore, its deprecated and will not work in newer PHP-versions. use mysqli_ or PDO instead. for the question: JaMaBing's comment should be the answer.

Comment: What error message do you get when this script is executed on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you didn't add the PHP end tag before your HTML. Try this:

```
<?php
    if($query = mysql_query("SELECT name,email,city,phone FROM personal_information WHERE id>'$id' AND username='$username'"))
    {
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0)
        {
?>
            <a href="cv/addcv.php"><img src="images/addcv.png" style="display: none;"> </a>
<?php
        }
        else
        {
?>
             <a href="cv/addcv.php"><img src="images/addcv.png" style="width:120px;height:120px"> </a>
<?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Two things. First you're not doing a comparison here -

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)=0) // you need != (not equal) or > (greater than) or == (equal to)
```

Secondly, you're not echoing your HTML markup. That should cause errors. You should either close the PHP tags or echo the markup so you get correct output. For instance:

```
echo '<a href="cv/addcv.php"><img src="images/addcv.png" style="display: none;"> </a>';
```

You should add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` so that you see all of the errors.

**Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). **Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)** instead, and **use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo).** **[You're inviting SQL injection!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)**

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)=0)
```

To

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query)==0)
```

Also: the mysql functions are deprecated. Please use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. If that is not an option for some reason, you can also use the mysqli functions, but PDO is recommended nowadays.